# DelimitMate Plugin: How can I specify my own delimiters? Also, can I jump the cursor to the end of the generated right-delims with an insert-mode map?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, insert-mode, delimiter-matching, plugin-delimitmate

Two questions related to the DelimitMate plugin here:

1. How can I modify the set of auto-generated left and right delimiters? For example, in LaTeX it would be convenient to have `$` as left-right delimiters, and if possible somehow, `\[` and `\]` (even though this includes the brackets, which the plugin seems to detect independent of the escape).
2. Is there any way to map some insert-mode keystroke to "move to the right" of the most recently generated right-delimeter? That would make editing certain types of files a lot easier. Something like `inoremap <C-l> <move to end of automatically-generated delimiter>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Look into the [delimitMate_quotes](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate/blob/master/doc/delimitMate.txt#L169) variable. The following line in your vimrc should take care of the `$` sign delimiter.

   `au FileType tex let b:delimitMate_quotes = "\" ' $"`

Not sure how you would go about setting a delimiter for `\[`.

2. Checkout some of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770836/vim-delimitmate/14771389).

Comment: Thanks! Do you know any way to modify unlike pairs as well? Weirdly, I found if I try to change `&matchpairs` with `set matchpairs="(:),{:},[:],<:>"`, the plugin completely breaks/stops working.

Comment: Yes. Use the `delimitMate_matchpairs` variable. The line you are looking for is `let delimitMate_matchpairs = "(:),{:},[:],<:>"`. I thought that this variable could perhaps be used to set `\[` as a delimiter as your question mentions, but it doesn't seem like it is able to accept a multi-character delimiter. See the [delimitMate doc](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate/blob/master/doc/delimitMate.txt#L156) for more info on this variable.

Comment: I've edited my answer to try and address your second question as well.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this, I figured out that to move "outside" a set of (), [], or {} can be accomplished with

```
inoremap ;; <Esc>l%%a
```

where I choose to use a double-semicolon, because I find in day-to-day typing that I *never* use the semicolon unless followed by a space, and its in a really convenient location. Also, while you **can't** really make arbitrary, multiple-character delimiters work inside of DelimitMate, you **can** make simple remaps for adding them; an example is my series of maps for bolding text in TeX documents:

```
au FileType tex inoremap <buffer> ;t \textbf{}<Left>
au FileType tex nnoremap <buffer> ;t mAlbi\textbf{<Esc>ea}<Esc>`A
au FileType tex vnoremap <buffer> ;t mA<Esc>`>a}<Esc>`<i\textbf{<Esc>`AF\
```

which bolds the **current word**, **current selection**, or just **adds** a `\textbf{}` during insert mode and puts the cursor inside the curly braces. The `<buffer>` makes the above maps local to the file being edited, so they won't be carried over e.g. if you are working on a `.py` file in another tab.